# Create a computed column and round

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have 3 `numeric(18,2)` columns in my table.  I want to create a `fourth column` that is `computed`.  I created the computed column in SSMS as `numeric (18,2)` just like the other 3 columns.

When I run a `SELECT` against my new column, it computes it fine, but it's not rounded to two decimal places.  I've tried using the `ROUND` function inside my computed column definition but that didn't work.  It reset my data type to `numeric (38,6)` and now won't let me change it.

My new column definition is `((Length * Width * Height) / 166)`

I want the end result rounded to two decimal places.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `computed column` to `numeric(18,2)`

**Example :**

```
CREATE TABLE computed
  (
     a NUMERIC(18, 2),
     b NUMERIC(18, 2),
     c AS CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), a * b)
  )

INSERT INTO computed VALUES (1,2)

SELECT *
FROM   computed
```